# EJBObject shared among clients?

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-2.x

Head first EJB states that in the case of stateless session beans:

> Clients don't share `EJBObject`, but the same bean can serve multiple
>   `EJBObjects`

I don't see any reason why a single EJBObject cannot serve multiple clients.
Furthermore, if what the book states is correct, what is the advantage we get from pooling beans if we have to create one EJBObject per client ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, one has to understand what an [`EJBObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJBObject.html) is:

> The *EJBObject* interface is extended by all enterprise beans' remote interfaces. An enterprise bean's remote interface **provides the remote client view of an EJB object**. An enterprise bean's remote interface defines the business methods callable by a remote client.

With that being cleared, consider the following local EJB example:

```
public class SomeClass {

    @EJB
    private SomeBean someBean;
    ...
}
```

Basically, our `EJBObject` is nothing more than an attribute of our class `SomeClass` which references the EJB `SomeBean`.

What's happening is that, on the container's point of view, he's not really creating and injecting a dedicated instance of the EJB `SomeBean`. Instead, he's instantiating the EJB `SomeBean`, storing it in his EJB pool, creating a *proxy* for this instance and injecting the proxy in on our class `SomeClass`.

Therefore, for each client, you have a single `EJBObject` or *proxy* but, under the hood, as the *Head First* states, *the same bean can serve multiple  `EJBObjects`*.

> ...what is the advantage we get from pooling beans if we have to create one EJBObject per client?

Well, for instance, **thread-safety**: if you have several instances of `SomeClass`, calling concurrently the same method of `someBean`, it is guaranteed that those calls will never be delegated to the same instance since *Stateless session instances are dedicated to an EJB object only for the duration of a single method call*.

Other advantages of EJB pooling can be found on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/135037/1346996) by [Will Hartung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13663/will-hartung). :)

Comment: Annotations don't work in remote clients so, your code snippet is incorrect. In remote clients, JNDI should be used to look up remote objects.

Comment: Your statement - "it is guaranteed that those calls will never be delegated to the same instance" is incorrect. The container may choose same instance. For instance, lets say there's a pool of 50 SLSBs. Client A makes a call and is assigned an instance. While this call is in process, lets say there are 49 other calls. So, the pool is empty now. Client A is done with its process and its associated SB is sent to pool. While other 49 SLSBs are still under process, now if the Client A makes another call, the container will assign same instance which was allocated first as its only the free one.

Comment: @mnmopazem first of all my code snippet **is correct** for local clients. Second of all, I'm not referring to any remote clients which you may argue is missing, that I agree. Finally, you ought to read carefully my answer before making any remark: I stated that **a concurrent call** will never be delegated to the same instance. The example you provide isn't at all related to what I've stated.

Comment: My statement is w.r.t a context which is specified in your answer. The `EJBObject` link that you specified points to JEE 6 API and `EJBObject` extends a remote interface.

Comment: Regarding concurrent call, I agree that example is unrelated to context. My apologies.

Comment: Edited my answer's example in order to comply with the EJB type. Thank you for the input.